# More efficient solution? Dictionary as sparse vector

Tags: python, performance, numpy, scipy, sparse-matrix

I have two dictionaries that I use as sparse vectors:

```
dict1 = {'a': 1, 'b': 4}
dict2 = {'a': 2, 'c': 2}
```

I wrote my own `__add__` function to get this desired result:

```
dict1 = {'a': 3, 'b': 4, 'c': 2}
```

It is important that I know the strings 'a', 'b' and 'c' for each corresponding value. Just making sure that I add up the correct dimensions is not enough. I will also get many more, previously unknown strings with some values that I just add to my dictionary at the moment.

Now my question: Is there a more efficient data structure out there? I looked at Numpy's arrays and Scipy's sparse matrixes but as far as I understand they are not really of any help here or am I just not seeing the solution?

I could keep keys and values in separate arrays but I don't think I can just use any already existing function to get the desired result.

```
dict1_keys   = np.array([a, b])
dict1_values = np.array([1, 4])
dict2_keys   = np.array([a, c])
dict2_values = np.array([2, 2])

# is there anything that will efficiently produce the following?
dict1_keys   = np.array([a, b, c])
dict1_values = np.array([3, 4, 2])
```

Comment: Do you really need your keys to be strings? Do you have a known number of keys or you want to handle merging/addition of any possible key?

Comment: Have a look at [the stuff](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/classes.html#module-sklearn.feature_extraction) in scikti-learn. I don't have experience with this kind of thing but I think it can do what you want.

Comment: It has to be strings. I could of course map the strings to number but I don't think that would speed up anything. Yes, more keys will be added later

Comment: The sparse `dok` format is a dictionary but its keys are a tuple - the 2 integer index values of a matrix. To do math it converts to `csr` format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/) is what you're looking for:

```
d1 = pandas.DataFrame(numpy.array([1, 4]), index=['a', 'b'], dtype="int32")
d2 = pandas.DataFrame(numpy.array([2, 2]), index=['a', 'c'], dtype="int32")

d1.add(d2, fill_value=0)
```

result:

```
   0
a  3
b  4
c  2
```

Answer (score 1):

@sirfz's [Pandas approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30414849/623735) could be a one-liner using pandas `Series`:

```
>>> pd.Series(dict1).add(pd.Series(dict2), fill_value=0)
a    3.0
b    4.0
c    2.0
```

Or if your API required `dict`s

```
>>> dict(pd.Series(dict1).add(pd.Series(dict2), fill_value=0))
{'a': 3.0, 'b': 4.0, 'c': 2.0}
```

Plus, this should handle mixed inputs of `dict`s or `Series`s or even `scipy` sparse matrix rows and `sklearn` `Vectorizer` output (sparse vectors/mappings)